# Compiling Mesa for Mac OS X 10.8 for an unsupported GPU

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-mountain-lion, mesa

Is it possible to compile Mesa for Mountain Lion. My Intel HD Graphics 2000 Mobile is unsupported, and OpenGL acceleration doesn't work if I move back the driver (kext) to /System/Library/Extensions/ I'm stuck on a grey screen. I'm thinking of using Mesa instead of Mac OS X built-in OpenGL. Is it possible to compile it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? What happened when you did? Also, are you aware that Mesa is a software renderer?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Mesa is a state tracker for which a software renderer fallback exists. On Linux Mesa implements GPU state trackers, i.e. drivers for GPUs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL is deeply integrated into MacOS X, hence it's virtually impossible to upgrade or change the OpenGL driver without an actual OS upgrade. Technically it's possible to compile the Mesa software renderer, but its performance is not very great; also there's no NSOpenGLView replacement for Mesa, so everything that would involve using that would be very hackish.

What kind of hardware are you trying to run this? Is this an actual MacBook or are you attempting to run a Hackintosh, i.e. a MacOS X on non-Apple HW?